# How to make a Normal Installation on Windows XP?

Tags: installation, wubi, windows-xp

I don't know if my question makes sense, but I am asking anyway if there is actually an answer.
From what I have read, a **regular** install performs better when compared to **Wubi** install.
My question is, is it possible to make a regular install on a Windows XP system, without using Wubi. If so, what is the procedure to do this?

Comment: What do you mean, "a regular install on a Windows XP system, without using Wubi"? A regular install would be on a separate partition from the Windows partition, and it would not be accurate to call it "a regular install *on* a Windows XP system".

Comment: @Flimm: Hmm, that's why I said my question may not make much sense :). So, I would have to create a new partition right? Could you provide some link that would give a step by step procedure on how to do that?

Comment: [Burn Ubuntu to a DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows), reboot your computer and boot from the DVD. You may need to modify your BIOS settings to allow booting from the DVD. Once you've done that, the installer will let you resize the Windows partition and create a new Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to do anything previous to simply just inserting the LiveCD or LiveUSB (Assuming this is what you call Regular install) of Ubuntu and just let the Ubuntu install process guide you.

It will tell you if you need to partition and let you adjust the size to the one you need. The LiveCD/LiveUSB of Ubuntu is very easy to use and will let you do the following things while you go through the installation process:

- Create, Resize, Delete partitions (It will not delete or damage a Windows partition if you don't want to)
- Import Windows user accounts (Like Administrator)
- Let you take a webcam picture for your Ubuntu user logo
- Setup all proprietary drivers if you select them in the installation process (To listen to MP3 songs, see some type of videos that use special codecs, see flash player enabled web sites, etc..)
- Encrypt your home folder, partition or hard drive
- Give you helpful hints while installing
- Will serve as a way to checking how Ubuntu will behave before installing it
- Only way right now to install Ubuntu if you had Windows 8

In your case, with Windows XP, just insert the LiveCD / LiveUSB, boot from it and enjoy the show. It is even easier than installing Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use disk manager in XP to make a partiton just don't format it with a filesystem. Link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309000

Answer (score 0):

First you need to un-install the Ubuntu version that was installed using the windows installer, and then defrag the windows partition, and then Just boot up a Live usb or DVD (do this by selecting the device you want to boot from in the bios of boot menu). If you want to duel boot just select install Ubuntu alongside Windows xp, and I would give Ubuntu at-least 40gb of disc space when you are prompted to select the partition size.

** Important** after the install is complete, and you want to boot xp  make sure you allow it to do an error check if prompted, if not it's a good idea to do it after xp boots.

I hope this helps.